# Las fechas de un archivo CSV no se abren correctamente desde VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Buen día. Estoy tratando de abrir un archivo .csv desde BVA y las fechas me abren con un formato diferente. Por ejemplo al abrir la fecha 04/10/2021, me interpreta 10/04/2021. Cuando abro el mismo archivo .csv con excel o un block de notas dando doble click sobre él, las fechas se visualizan correctamente, pero cuando lo abro desde una macro a través de VBA, las fechas se muestran incorrectas. El problema es que ya no puedo manipular los formatos, pues enseguida que se abre ya la interpretación es diferente, por lo que incluso el formato en número de la fecha ya es de abril y no de octubre (44296.00). ¿Existe algún parámetro en la función workbooks.open en el que pueda determinar el idioma y configuraciones regionales con las que quiero que se abra el archivo?
Gracias de antemano.

El código para abrir el archivo es el siguiente:

```
    If Dir(ruta & "\" & nombre_ext) <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ruta & "\" & nombre_ext
```

Comment: Muestra el código VBA que usas para ver el archivo CSV, y así será más fácil ayudarte. Un Saludo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: He añadido el código con el que estoy abriendo el archivo para mejor referencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ruta & "\" & nombre_ext, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4), Local:=True
```

Usa este código. El problema de las fechas es un bug reconocido por Microsoft a la hora de abrir ficheros csv. Pero para solucionarlo, debes de usar el método OpenText (Open es más limitado). La clave es el parámetro Local:=True, que establece la variable de configuración regional...

Si no te funciona, muestra el fichero csv para ver cómo están delimitados los datos, si con coma o los puntos... (textQualifier)

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto, el archivo csv sí está separado por comas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!